# Where is the PHP executable on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, ubuntu-8.10

I have installed Apache and PHP. I know PHP works as I have tested a simple PHP file on an Apache server.

I'm writing a simple webserver which should be able to process PHP files. So once I get a request for a PHP file, I want to do something like 'exec php test.php' and get the output and pass it to the client.

As I'm not much into Ubuntu, I don't know where the PHP executable is (should be in \bin right?) to do it. But there is no PHP file inside \bin or \usr\bin.

When I run 'which php' it shows nothing. How do I do this?

Comment: What happened is most likely that you got php in apache as php module (technically - a library not an executable binary that gets called externally), that's why you couldn't find the binary. This comment is meant to complete the answer, which tells you what needs to be done to get the php binary in your system but doesn't provide any reasons why it was missing.

Comment: If you are really running Ubuntu 8.10 like your tags suggest, you should understand Ubuntu 8.10 is extremely out of date.  You really should upgrade ASAP.  There is no security support for that release.

Comment: @Zoredache yeah I know it's very old. But I'm not a Ubuntu user. I had the CD and I installed it, just for my assignment! :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the `php5-cli` or `php5-cgi` package.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
# OR
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```

As Zoredache noted in the comment. cli version doesn't process headers nor dos output them - it's sort of clean PHP interpreter completely unaware of HTTP.

If you want version capable of above mentioned, use the CGI version.

Comment: yeah I just learned I need php-cli..:)

Comment: Since he is writing a web server, he probably *doesn't* want the CLI version since that isn't going to be able to get the GET/POST data.

Comment: ok, installed, still question: where is the executable?

Answer (score 19):

Type the following in your terminal

> whereis php

Comment: I got this `php: /usr/bin/php7.1 /usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php7.2 /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/include/php /usr/share/php7.1-opcache /usr/share/php7.2-zip /usr/share/php7.0-intl /usr/share/php7.1-common /usr/share/php7.0-gd /usr/share/php7.2-common /usr/share/php7.1-gd /usr/share/php7.1-xmlrpc /usr/share/php7.2-intl /usr/share/php7.2-mysql `

Answer (score 13):

I found the executables in **/usr/bin/**

eg:

- /usr/bin/php
- /usr/bin/php7.0
- /usr/bin/php7.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are **writing** your own web server you almost certainly want to install or build the CGI version of the PHP binary, and you will want to implement the CGI protocol in your web server. The CGI version has the required facilities to capture the GET/POST data.

See:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Comment: I'm writing a simple web server with PHP and CGI support. For parsing php files, what I'm gonna do is 'exec /usr/bin/php file.php'. And you can run CGI scripts by parsing them to perl. Am I right? feasible?

Comment: Uhm, no CGI hasnothing to do with perl.  You really should read at least the wikipedia article.